# android carousel with animation

Tags: android-animation

I want to have a animation(ex:fadeout) when I touch the selected image.
I use the carousel example here:[Android 3D Carousel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel)

my codes is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //Animation fadeout = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout);


    Carousel carousel = (Carousel)findViewById(R.id.carousel);
    carousel.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {                
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Position=" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(position==0){
                String toastMessage = String.format("RFID");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Animation anim = null;  
                anim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f,+360.0f);  
                anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());  
                anim.setDuration(30000);
                findViewById(R.id.carousel).startAnimation(anim);    

                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(MainActivity.this, web_rfid.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }

        }

    });
}
```

}
I want the selected image to be rotated, but the result is whole screen rotated.
The problem is

```
findViewById(R.id.carousel).startAnimation(anim);
```

But I don't know how to find out the selected image in my code.
Plz hlep me.
Thanks.